# how to open chrome extension if click some text in the browser window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

> I need to open the chrome extension if i click some text in the chrome browser window , rather than go the extension icon and clicked
>   it manually. if it is blocked by chrome is there a way to create a plugin and open it without click

Comment: You cannot open the popup window programmatically. You could open it in a different window/tab but like clicking on the extension's icon you can't.

Comment: how to can i open extension in different window which i click some text or link in browser window